The program does not re-run instead the else statement is executed
Recently, I created this simple game in VS Code. However, if I try to run the code when the game is asking for input, the undefined statement (which I wrote for cases when the input is invalid, check code with #UNDEFINED ERROR ) is executed only . The program does not re-run instead the else(check code with #UNDEFINED ERROR) statement is executed for invalid input in IDE.
MY THEORY IS WHEN I PRESS RUN IN VS CODE IT ENTER CERTAIN SYMBOL TO TELL  COMPILER TO RE-RUN THE PROGRAM BUT WHEN PROGRAM IS ASKIG FOR INPUT IN TERMINAL IT GETS INTERPRETED AS INVALID INPUT I AM NOT SURE AS IT HAS NOT HAPPENED BEFORE.
import random  # Importing the random module to generate random numbers

# Initializing variables
inp = 1
comp_won = user_won = 0

# Printing the welcome message and instructions
print("WELCOME TO GUESS THE NUMBER!\n\nEnter: \n'0' for answer\n'-1' for exit\n\nBEST OF 3:\n")


# Main game loop: continues until the user inputs -1 or either player wins 3 rounds
while int(inp) != -1 and user_won != 3 and comp_won != 3:
    try_remain = 7  # Number of attempts for each round
    num_to_guess = random.randint(1, 100)  # Generating a random number between 1 and 100


    # Loop for each round: continues until attempts run out or the user guesses correctly
    while try_remain > 1:
        inp = input(f"Guess the number ({try_remain-1} attempts left): ")  # Prompting user for input
        
        if inp.isdigit():  # Checking if the input is a digit
            if int(inp) == num_to_guess:  # If the guess is correct
                user_won += 1
                print(f"You won this round!!!\nScore: {user_won}:{comp_won}\n")
                break

            elif num_to_guess < int(inp) <= 100:  # If the guess is too high
                print("Hint: The number is lesser")
                try_remain -= 1

            elif int(inp) == 0:  # Special case for input 0
                try_remain -= 6

            elif int(inp) == -1:  # Special case for input -1
                print(f"\nThe number was {num_to_guess}")
                print("Exiting program...")
                break

            elif 0 < int(inp) < num_to_guess:  # If the guess is too low
                print("Hint: The number is greater")
                try_remain -= 1

            else:  # If the input is out of the valid range
                print("Input should be an integer between 1-100")

        else:  #UNDEFINED ERROR If the input is not a digit
            with open(r'prize.txt', 'a+') as f:  # Opening the prize file
                f.seek(0)
                l = [li.strip() for li in f.readlines()]  # Reading the prize codes


                if inp.upper() in l:  # Checking if the input matches a prize code
                    print(f"\nThe number was {num_to_guess}")
                    user_won += 1
                    print(f"You won this round!!!\nScore: {user_won}:{comp_won}\n")
                    l.remove(inp)  # Removing the used prize code
                    with open(r"prize.txt", 'w') as f:  # Writing the updated prize codes back to the file
                        for it in l:
                            f.write(f"{try_remain}\n")
                    inp = 1
                    break

            print("Input should be an integer between 1-100")


    else:  # If the user fails to guess the number within the allowed attempts
        print(f"The number was {num_to_guess}")
        comp_won += 1
        print(f"You lost this round!!!\nScore: {user_won}:{comp_won}\n")



# End of game: printing the final scores and determining the winner
else:
    print(f"Your score: {user_won}\nComputer score: {comp_won}\n")
    if user_won > comp_won and int(inp) != -1:
        print("You won the game!!!")
        prize = "".join(random.sample('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 4))  # Generating a random prize code
        with open(r"prize.txt", 'a') as f:  # Saving the prize code to the file
            f.write(f"{prize}\n")
            print(f"Use code-{prize} in the next round for an instant victory")
    else:
        print("Computer won!!!")

#ELSE OR UNDEFINED STATEMENT:
else:  # If the input is not a digit
                with open(r'prize.txt', 'a+') as f:  # Opening the prize file
                f.seek(0)
                l = [li.strip() for li in f.readlines()]  # Reading the prize codes


                if inp.upper() in l:  # Checking if the input matches a prize code
                    print(f"\nThe number was {num_to_guess}")
                    user_won += 1
                    print(f"You won this round!!!\nScore: {user_won}:{comp_won}\n")
                    l.remove(inp)  # Removing the used prize code
                    with open(r"prize.txt", 'w') as f:  # Writing the updated prize codes back to the file
                        for it in l:
                            f.write(f"{try_remain}\n")
                    inp = 1
                    break

            print("Input should be an integer between 1-100")

expectation:
#FIRST TIME PROGRAM IS RUN:

WELCOME TO GUESS THE NUMBER!

enter: 
'0' for answer
'-1' for exit

BEST OF 10:

guess the number(6): 50
Hint: no. is greater
guess the number(5):

#NOW RUN BUTTON IS PRESSED AGAIN:

WELCOME TO GUESS THE NUMBER!

enter: 
'0' for answer
'-1' for exit

BEST OF 10:

guess the number(6):

#PROGRAM RE-RUN AGAIN SUCCESSFULLY

REAL OUTPUT:
#FIRST TIME PROGRAM IS RUN:

WELCOME TO GUESS THE NUMBER!

enter: 
'0' for answer
'-1' for exit

BEST OF 10:

guess the number(6): 50
Hint: no. is greater
guess the number(5):

#NOW RUN BUTTON IS PRESSED AGAIN:

guess the number(5): python -u "c:\Users\vatsa\OneDrive\Desktop\vatsal_vscode\tkinter\staa.py"
input should be integer between 1-100
guess the number(5):

#PROGRAM DOES NOR RE COMPILE INSTEAD WE GET OUTPUT LIKE WE HAVE PASSED SOME VALUE TO INPUT FUNCTION


We don't know what "the undefined statement" and "the else statement" mean.  Don't make us guess.  Please show the EXACT output, so we can see what code is actually executed.

@JohnGordon i have used tag #UNDEFINED ERROR to highlight the else statement also specially defined else statement to mend any confusion so please check code again to identify the problem

Your question is still confusing.  What does "undefined error" mean?  What does "the program does not re-run" mean?

@JohnGordon undefined error simply mean the else statement i have created for cases where user enter string when the program expects integer kind of exception handling but in my vs code when program expects an input from user and i click on run(to override everything and compile program again) it run this else statement like i have enter an unexpected value and program does not re-run. i have to close vs code and open again to restart program. feel free to ask if this question  still causes any confusion

When I run this code and enter a string instead of a number, the program responds with the message "Input should be an integer between 1-100", and prompts me for input again.  Are you saying the code does not do this when you run it?

@JohnGordon nope that works well for me too but when the program ask you to enter input try re-running the program the program will not re run as it should instead "Input should be an integer between 1-100"will appear on the terminal as if you have enter string when program expected integer

but when the program ask you to enter input try re-running the program the program will not re run as it should Are you saying that when the program asks for input, you somehow terminate the program and then run it again?  This question is so confusing.

normally you can re-run the program at any given time click on run again and program will begin to compile from the beginning .In this case  the program the program will not re run instead "Input should be an integer between 1-100"will appear on the terminal

click on run again This sounds like a question about your particular environment, instead of a general python question.

honestly i am not very sure for cause of the problem if it is due to environment or something is wrong in the code however i would like to request you to 1) try running the code and 2) when it ask you to enter input instead of guessing the number re-run(step - 1) the program and see if the program get compiled from the beginning for you as it does not in my case

@JohnGordon i have made several edit to the initial question pasting expectation of how code should have worked and what actual output is see if now you can identify problem in this code

I don't know how visual studio is supposed to behave if you re-run a program that is already running.  Maybe a visual studio expert can help.

I'm not going to give you answers, but I will be glad to go over what I see are probably issues with your code.  There are a couple of issues that I see, but check them for yourself as I did not run the code:
You are reading this in and it produces a list of strings:
l = [li.strip() for li in f.readlines()]  # Reading the prize codes

My suggestion here is that you decide which type - str or int - to work with.  Choose one and work with that one.  I'd choose integer and do the conversions at the point of introduction - the input statement and reading the prize codes above.
And then you test the integer variable 'inp' declared above as:
# Initializing variables
inp = 1

as if it where a string against a list of strings for equivalence.  Keep in mind you have now called upper() against an integer.  Execute the command:
dir(int)

and you will see that there is NOT attribute named upper() in pythons int type.
 if inp.upper() in l:  # Checking if the input matches a prize code

also, the input statement never converts the string input to an integer
  inp = input(f"Guess the number ({try_remain-1} attempts left): ")  # Prompting user for input

and as a last observation, you are not closing the input file before you open it again. 'with' blocks are powerful, I've used them extensively for resource management, but they must be used correctly.  On the initial open there is no need to rewind the file pointer as it will always start at the beginning:
  with open(r'prize.txt', 'a+') as f:  # Opening the prize file
                f.seek(0)

this opens the same file again without closing it overwriting the original
'f' handle with a new handle opened with a different open() attribute.  By not closing it you introduce either an unhandled run-time write share lock error or risk file corruption (or both).
with open(r"prize.txt", 'w') as f:  # Writing the updated prize codes back to the file

So in summary there are type collision issues (int <-> str), and possible file corruption issues as well.  Good luck, see if fixing those solves the problems you are having.

you should probably do while int(inp) != -1 and user_won < 3 and comp_won < 3: and while try remaining is > 0:
also the indentation:
        if inp.isdigit():  # Checking if the input is a digit
            ...

        elif inp == '-1':  # Special case for input -1
            print(f"\nThe number was {num_to_guess}")
            print("Exiting program...")
            break

        else:  # If the input is not a digit
            with open('prize.txt', 'a+') as f:  # Opening the prize file
                f.seek(0)
                l = [li.strip() for li in f.readlines()]  # Reading the prize codes

                if inp.upper() in l:
                    ...
                    break
                else:
                    print("Input should be an integer between 1-100 or a valid prize code.")

